# .bat to run python script using anaconda prompt

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, anaconda

I want to execute a python script by using `.bat` file. I am using anaconda prompt.

```
Call "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" 
"C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe","C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Test_2.py" 
pause
```

Error is

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] button, and format the output content as a Code Sample. Please also take the tour, and read through the linked content of [ask]. Please also replace the comma in your command line, with a space.

Comment: @Compo  Code works fine after removing comma as you suggested. Thank you for your guidance.